# How to check if the hardware keypad is available or not? (Blackberry)

Tags: java, blackberry, hardware

Is there any way to detect whether a hardware keypad is available or not in Blackberry?

Answer (score 4):

You should definitely use class [DeviceCapability](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/6.0.0api/net/rim/device/api/system/capability/DeviceCapability.html), introduced in BlackBerry OS 6, to find out if a keypad is available or not.

> "DeviceCapability Provides a way to query the host device's
>   capabilities. You can use this class to determine capability in three
>   ways: to find out if a feature is supported, allowed, or available."